# Problems with layout

Tags: android, android-layout, unicode

I am trying to create my own Phone Dialer from scratch in Eclipse Android, I did a simple phone layout in the XML with numbers 0-9 and some Buttons/ImageButtons.

- Basically I put some `Button`s and `ImageButton`s and I understand that I need call `setOnClickListener()` on them in the Java code. Something like:

  ```
  Button no1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  no1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  ```
- I did an `<EditText` on top of the numbers (Buttons and ImageButtons) to display the numbers. But nothing come out when I click. I am not sure what I miss out which cause this problem.
- I also did a "settings" button in the same XML file, which upon clicking on the button, a toast will pop out which have a couple of clickable icons. I am not too sure on how to do it. I did read some tutorials but mine seems to be not quite right.
- hopefully if the above-mentioned points can be rectified, I hope I can try to make the SMS characters to be Unicode, which can limit to lets say 50 characters etc.. but that's still far-fetched for me though. I'll do this in the later part.

I did a Google research but I don't quite get the correct info as its just bits and pieces here and there...

Actually I want to create this customized phone dialer as I intent to install it in my Mum's 2.1 Froyo phone.

Can anyone advise me please? Is there a sample code where I can check what I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your class implement OnClickListener and make a switch(arg0.getId()) and a case for each number pressed.

Every time you press a number have an EditText receive that number and then when you press the call button have it call the numbers in that EditText.

Comment: hi guys thanks for the tips.. i kind of getting the program to work now.. barely.. just figuring out how to call after i input some numbers in the edittext..

Comment: hi guys, the numbers that i pressed can be seen in my edittext, but when i clicked on the call button(a button that i create in xml), nothing happens. how do i make a call after i input some values in my edittext?? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In that amount of time, the application may still have some flaws in it.  But you are on the right track.  I would have your class xxx.java extend `View.OnClickListener`, then you can add your class as the listener for each button, e.g. `no1.setOnClickListener(this);`.  Use a switch statement to figure out the phone number and make the call.

Comment: the numbers that i pressed can be seen in my edittext, but when i clicked on the call button(a button that i create in xml), nothing happens. how do i make a call after i input some values in my edittext?? thanks in advance.